# Easy proof that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=\tan(x) \}$ is a closed set.

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to know whether there's an "easy" proof that $$A:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=\tan(x) \} .$$

I've tried to prove that its complement is open, but given an $(x,y)$ such that $\tan(x) \neq y$, it's a bit of a grind to find (in the general case) an open set that contains $(x,y)$ and does not intersect $A$. Is there a simpler argument using basic euclidean topology?

Some of the comments here gave me an idea: If $U:=\{{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: cos(x) \neq 0}\}$ and $f:U -> \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x,y)=y-tan(x)$, then$A=f^{-1}(\{0\})$, therefore A is closed in U. Does this imply that A is closed in \mathbb{R}^2, though?

Comment: What can you say about $f(x, y) =y-tan(x) $ in terms of regularity  ?

Comment: Hint: there are two cases to consider, depending on whether $\tan(x)$ is defined.

Comment: @EDX Only continuous when $cos(x) \neq 0$, isn't it?

Comment: Is $f(x)=\tan(x)$ continuous? If so, then since its codomain is Hausdorff, its graph will be closed in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}:k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang is it true that if F is closed on A and A in open on B, then F is closed on B? Because if that's the case I think I found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is any topological space and $A\subseteq X$ and $X=\bigcup_n U_n$, where $U_n$ are open, then $A$ is closed if and only if $A\cap U_n$ is closed for all $n$.

Now, if you consider $X=\mathbf R^2$ and $U_n=(-n,n)^2$, then it is clear that each $A\cap U_n$ is closed (e.g. because $A\cap \overline U_n$ is compact).

Answer (score 2):

If $p\in A^c:=\Bbb R^2\setminus A$, let the perpendicular from $p$ to $A$ have length $r$: then the open neighbourhood of $p$ of radius $r$ is a subset of $A^c$, so $A^c$ is open. You can formalize the result that $r>0$ with $A$'s radius of curvature.

Comment: Interesting. What's a radius of curvature?

Comment: @David [Basically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature#Formula), the radius of curvature of $A$ at some $p\in A$ is the radius of the unique circle through $p$ that matches $A$'s first two derivatives at $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ is closed in $X \times Y$, assuming $Y$ is hausdoff (you can google this result or even better, prove it). The $\tan$ function is not continuous however but it is continuous on each interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}+ n \pi , \frac{\pi}{2}+ n \pi )$.

Hence, you only must check that it is closed in those slices that are not covered by those intervals, so only for $x =\frac{\pi}{2}+n \pi$, so just find an open set that does not intersect $\tan$ for each $(\frac{\pi}{2}+n \pi, y)$. This is much more easier to do just using facts about the $\tan$ function.

Comment: But how can I move from the "slices" of $A$ being closed to $A$ itself being closed?

Comment: @David I am not pasting the slices of the function, by the way, but the whole slices of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it's fine to paste infinitely many of them. If $A$ is closed in $X$ and $Y$ then it is closed in $X \cup Y$, for assume that is not the case: $A$ is open in $X \cup Y$. So $A$ has a limit point $x_0$ such that it is not in $A$. That means there is some open set containing $x_0$ that does not intersect neither $X$ or $Y$, hence $A$ is open  in either $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: @Shiranai: This does not quite work. This will only show that $A$ is closed in $\operatorname{dom}\tan\times \mathbf R$. Since this is not a closed subset of the plane, this does not obviously pass to being closed in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A= \{(x,y) | x \notin {\pi \over 2} \mathbb{Z}, \ y = \tan x \}$.

Suppose $(x_k, \tan x_k ) \to (x,y)$. In particular, for large $k$ we have
$|y-\tan x_k| \le 1$ and so
$\tan x_k \in [y-1,y+1]$.

Hence $x_k \in \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} I_n$, where $I_n = [\arctan (y-1)+n \pi, \arctan (y+1) +n \pi]$.

Note that if $n \neq n'$ and $a \in I_n, b \in I_{n'}$ then
$|a-b| \ge \pi-\max(|\arctan (y-1)|, |\arctan (y+1)|) > 0$.

Since $x_k \to x$, there must be some $n$ such that $x_k \in I_n$ for a countable number of $k$ and since $I_n$ is closed, we have $x \in I_n$.

Since $\tan$ is continuous on $I_n$, we see that $\tan x_k \to \tan x = y$
and so $(x,y) \in A$.

Answer (score -1):

You know that

Introducing $A_k=] -\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi[$

$$ f(x, y) =y-tan(x) $$

$f$ is continous on each set$G_k={ A_k} \times \mathbb{R} $ where sit the zeros.

$$ A=f^{-1}(\{0\}) $$

because $f$ is continous on each$G_k$ where sit the zeros and the reciprocal image of a closed set by a continous function is closed hence

**A** is closed in $\cup G_k$

In order to get to the slides take $(x_n,y_n)=((\pi/2+1/n) ,\tan(1/n-\pi/2)) $

$$y_n-\tan(x_n) = \dfrac{\sin(\pi)} {\cos(\pi/2 +1/n)\cos(\pi/2-1/n)} =0$$

So you can complete the missing lines...

Comment: But how does each $A_k$ being closed imply $A$ is also closed?

Comment: $A_k$ arent closed but $\mathbb{R}-A_k$ does. And it is principaly the fact that $\{0\} $is closed

Comment: I mean, I have infinitely many "closed slices" of A. How can I know the union of them is also closed?

Comment: Use only the fact that $f$ is continous so $f^{-1}(\{0\})$  must be also closed.